# Can't display time as String in react, using intl FormattedTime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I have this code:

```
var message = "The event starts at {1}";
var startTime = <FormattedTime value={new Date(eventData.startDateTime)}/>;
message = message.replace("{1}", startTime);

return (
  <div>
    {message}
    <br/>
    <FormattedTime value={new Date(eventData.startDateTime)}/><br/>
  </div>                    
);
```

This prints as:

```
The event starts at [object Object]
5:55 PM
```

I have a feeling this has more to do with javascript than react, but... why does it print as [object Object] in one case and the correct time in another?

Is there a way to get my event string with the correct time?

Comment: You aren't rendering your `<FormattedTime />` object to HTML when you do `message.replace`, you are stringifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is due to trying to use what's a dom object as a variable, one solution is to do the whole thing in HTML and do the string replace using intl's FormattedMessage. This only happens to work because I am already using something inside curly brackets for my strings that are to be substituted.

```
<FormattedMessage id="message" 
   defaultMessage="The event starts at {1}" 
   values={{ 1: startTime }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`FormattedTime` returns an object. If you want to return a string, you must use the function `formatTime`.

You can get it by calling the function `injectInlt` from 'react-intl' to your component. The function will be in `this.props.intl.formatTime()`.

```
formatTime(Date.now()); // "4:03 PM"
```